# How to test if a browser supports HTTP/3?

Tags: browser

I have been searching the web but I can't find any test to see if the browser I'm using is currently supporting HTTP/3 and if it is enabled. The websites I find are only for testing if websites support HTTP/3. Is there any website for testing if a browser supports HTTP/3?

Comment: Note that if you're behind a proxy, as I am, the tests given in the answer will be testing whether the proxy supports HTTP/3. You could get a false positive -- test site reports success because proxy supports it when your browser doesn't -- or you could get a false negative -- test site reports failure because proxy doesn't support it even though browser does.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## quic.nginx.org

You can test if your browser supports HTTP/3 at [quic.nginx.org](https://quic.nginx.org/) which is hosted by NGINX. The test doesn't usually require a page reload.

This is what it looks like for me:

[image: Successful test at quic.nginx.org]

## http3.is

You can also use [http3.is](https://http3.is/) by Fastly, but it might also require a page reload before it works.

This is what http3.is looks like for me (with HTTP/3 supported):

[image: Successful test at http3.is]

## cloudflare-quic.com

Cloudflare offers a HTTP/3 test at [cloudflare-quic.com](https://cloudflare-quic.com/). I had to reload the page twice for it to work.

This is what it looks like for me after a reload (with HTTP/3 supported):

[image: Successful test at cloudflare-quic.com]

Comment: Why is reloading necessary?

Comment: @PedroA because the `Alt-Svc` mechanism works kind of like HSTS. The browser makes an initial request using HTTP2, and the response to that request includes a header telling the browser that it can try HTTP3 for that domain in the future.

Comment: The http3.is website is the least reliable, the other ones required 1 reload in oder to work, but the http3.is website keeps saying my browser does not support http3

Comment: @Ferrybig I've been having some issues with quic.nginx.org lately as well so I've changed the order.

Answer (score 5):

To see which resources a website sends over HTTP/3:

1. Go to a website that supports HTTP/3, like one of those in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1664708/59284).
2. Open the **Network** tab of your browser's developer tools.
3. Right-click the header of the network log table and select **Protocol**.

   [image: Menu]